# Getting ClassCast Exception

Tags: android, classcastexception

My application got crashed because of class cast exception. I understood that class cast exception on Edit Text and but i am unable to solve this. I tried a lot on this error. Please Make it worked.
My java Code:

```
public static final int targetVendorID = 1155;      
    public static final int targetProductID = 22336;
    public  UsbManager manager;
    public  UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
    public  UsbInterface usbInterfaceFound = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointOut = null;
    public  UsbEndpoint endpointIn = null;
    public  UsbDevice usbdevice,device_details;
    public  UsbEndpoint listusbendpoint;
    public LifeTest Life_Test_child;
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devicelist= null;
    int selectedendpoint; 
    static int Coil_No;
    private static final int VID = 1155;
    private static final int PID = 22336;
    private static UsbDriver Usb_Driver_class;
    public static UsbDriver USB_Driver_Child;
    public static boolean Communication_Failed,Frame_Ok,Total_Frame_Decoded;
    static byte[] Communication_Byte;

    ActionBar actionbar;
    UsbConnectionHandler connectionHandler;
    Button clear,signin;
    public EditText username_edt,password;
    String i = "";
    Intent i2;
    String User_Name=null;
    TextView title;
    ByteBuffer buffer;
    String Shared_username,shared_pass;

    static byte[] sample;
    static boolean Communication_Ok;
    public static float []Wave_Form_Data=new float[1500];
    public static float []Wave_Form_Data_1=new float[1500];
    public static float Respsonse_Time,Drive_Voltage;
    static int Sequence_No,Response_Time;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

        actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.hide();
        username_edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                {
                    Communication_Byte=new byte[1];
                    User_Name=username_edt.getText().toString();

                    if(User_Name.toLowerCase().equals("medequip") && password.getText().toString().equals("medequip"))
                    {
                        if(Check_Devices_Available()==true)
                        {   
                            int Packet_Size = USB_Driver_Child.Data_In_End_Point.getMaxPacketSize();
                            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,""+Packet_Size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if(!Receive.isAlive())
                            {
                            Receive.start();
                            }
                            else
                            Receive.stop();
                            Communication_Ok=false;
                            for(int i=0;(i<5 && Communication_Ok!=true);i++)    
                            Send_Communication_Check_Command();

                            if(Communication_Ok)
                                Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, "Communication Successfully Established", 1000).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, "Communication Failure", 10000).show();

                            i2 = new Intent(Loginpage.this,TestsPage.class);
                            startActivity(i2);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Invalid username and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }       
            });

        clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
            username_edt.setText("");
            password.setText("");
            }
        });
       }


    @SuppressLint("ShowToast") @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access" })
    public boolean  Check_Devices_Available() 
    {
        Usb_Driver_class = new UsbDriver(this, connectionHandler, VID, PID);

        if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==0)
        {

            if(USB_Driver_Child.USB_Device_Connection==null || USB_Driver_Child.Data_Out_End_Point==null)
            return false;   

            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Device Found", 1000).show(); 
            return true;
        }
        else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"No Devices Attached ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            return false;
        }
        else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Device Found,But No End Points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            return false;
        }
        else if(USB_Driver_Child.Device_Exception==3)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this,"Unable to Open Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            return false;
        }
        return false;   //un known exception
    }

Thread Receive  = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Sequence_No=0;
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1500);
        sample = new byte[1500];
        int Frame_Size;
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        int i,j;
        byte [] datarx=new byte[1]; 
        char q;
        while (true) 
        {
        request.initialize(UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection, UsbDriver.Data_In_End_Point);
        request.queue(buffer, 1500);
        if (UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.requestWait() == request) 
        {
                sample=buffer.array(); 
                for(i=0;i<1500;i++)
                {
                        if(sample[i]=='&')
                        {
                            Communication_Ok=true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(sample[i]==0x03)
                        {
                            if(sample[0]==0x02)
                            Frame_Ok=true;  
                            break;
                        }

                }
                if(Frame_Ok==true)
                {
                    Frame_Ok=false;
                    if(sample[1]==1)
                    Coil_No=1;
                    else
                    Coil_No=2;
                    Response_Time= (int)(((sample[2]&0x00FF)<<8) + (sample[3]&0x00FF));

                    Total_Frame_Decoded=true;
                    sample = null;
                }   
        }
      }
    }
  });


private static void Send_Communication_Check_Command() 
{
    long i,j;

    Communication_Byte[0]='&';
    UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.bulkTransfer(UsbDriver.Data_Out_End_Point,Communication_Byte, 1, 0);
    for(i=0;(i<1000 && Communication_Ok!=true) ;i++)    
    for(j=0;(j<1000 && Communication_Ok!=true);j++);
}
//Test_Name=1; For Drive Response Test
//Test_Name=2; For Drive Life Test
//Test_Name=3; To Stop test 

public static void Send_Command_For_Drive_Response_Test(int Test_Name)
{
    int i;
    byte []Command_To_Transfer= new byte[5];
    Communication_Ok=false;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {   
        Send_Communication_Check_Command();
        if(Communication_Ok==true)
        break;  
    }
    if(Communication_Ok==true)
    {
        Command_To_Transfer[0]='*';
        if(Test_Name==1)
        {
            Command_To_Transfer[1]=Command_To_Transfer[2]=(byte) 0xA1;
        }
        else if(Test_Name==2)
        {
            Command_To_Transfer[1]=Command_To_Transfer[2]=(byte) 0xA2;
        }
        else if(Test_Name==3)
        {
            Command_To_Transfer[1]=Command_To_Transfer[2]=(byte) 0xA3;
        }
        Command_To_Transfer[3]=0; //For Future Reference 
        Command_To_Transfer[4]='#';
        UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.bulkTransfer(UsbDriver.Data_Out_End_Point,Command_To_Transfer, 5, 0);
        Communication_Failed=true;
    }
    else
    {
        Communication_Failed=false;
    }
}
```

This is mylogcat:

```
01-02 02:58:58.080: W/dalvikvm(9343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41765700)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo2c1testpanel/com.example.demo2c1testpanel.Loginpage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at com.example.demo2c1testpanel.Loginpage.onCreate(Loginpage.java:71)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 02:58:58.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

this is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/light_font" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/light_font" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/user_name_hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="570dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/Login_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.36"

            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="@string/clear"
         />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:text="@string/signin" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is at line `71` in `Loginpage`?

Comment: *Button  cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText*, you declared a `Button`in your layout and you are casting it to `EditText`

Comment: it was a reference to the edit text field @MD

Comment: Hi lakshman, Please paste your XML also. So we can help you out.

Comment: @lakshman What is that? post it

Comment: i placed  my XML file @Vivek

Comment: Your xml seems good, do one thing just clean and rebuild your project. Run again. This type of problem sometime happen also with me.

Comment: Like Vivek said, clean & rebuild. I have seen this kind of problems a lot

Comment: By clicking on Cleaning my project many errors occured dude. Importing problems occured @Vivek

Comment: Please share what you are facing now. is your R file deleted after cleaning the project?

Comment: Yup buddie.My R.java Files were deleted.How could i overcome this

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you declared `R.id.edt_username` or `R.id.edt_password` (or both) as a Button in your layout file (`R.layout.loginpage`). Change it to EditText.